# Connectivity Issue

Tags: azure, azure-devtest-labs

We are testing out DevTest Labs and having some issues related to connectivity.

Our set up is a CentOS VM with shared IP with 3 more VMs.

We installed MongoDB with port 37017 and trying to connect to it remotely. We checked and there is no firewall enabled in the VM. We added a rule on a virtual network for port 37017 and added a rule as well on the inbound NAT rules portion.

With the above configurations, we cannot connect using [RoboMongo](https://robomongo.org/).

Are we missing a configuration that will solve this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Um.. It's hard to specify what the cause is. Try to use tools like [Psping](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/sysinternals/downloads/psping) to the VM with the port to troubleshoot futher. Also ,if you get any error message please update your question.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you can connect to MongoDB via localhost on port 37017 (considering the default port is 27017)? Have you checked the `bind_ip` parameter to see if you're only listening on localhost? Lastly: note that this isn't a programming question and is better suited for ServerFault, as it's all about server and network configuration.